# Flutter SelectionArea get highlighted text

Tags: flutter, selection, highlight

With the Flutter 3.3, now we have `SelectionArea()` which works great and I can select multiple text inside multiple widgets.

However I have my own "right-click" menu which I need to disable when there are highlighted texts.

How do I detect if any text is highlighted by `SelectionArea()` or even better, have some sort of text controller to get the highlighted text?

Comment: Found this article which seems to show how to get the selected text within a selectionarea, but I haven't read it carefully yet. 
https://medium.com/@roperluo.me/with-the-official-release-of-flutter-3-3-22cba0c121cc